# Increase number delimited with dots from params file

Tags: awk, grep, increment

I have few params in my params.txt

```
config_version = "1.2.3" 

test_version = "1.2.3" 

version_count = "1.2.3" 

service_name = "test"
```

> already have answer from this forum how to get this number as output:
>
> ```
> awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ \"]+"}/config_version =/{print $3}' /dir/params.txt
> ```

I need to increase number of config_version value +1 for each awk one liner run. Examples:

> first value is 1.2.3, after awk command run --> 1.2.4 and save back to
> file
>
> first value is 1.200.1, after awk command run --> 1.200.2 and save
> back to file
>
> first values is 8.999.99, after awk command run --> 9.000.0 and save
> back to file

after each run of awk command the params.txt config_version will be updated to increased value

params.txt after 5 awk script execution:

```
config_version = "1.2.8" 

test_version = "1.2.3" 

version_count = "1.2.3" 

service_name = "test"
```

It all runs on Gitlab CI and only one-liner will be the option I can use.

```sh
"Gitlab job run (1) -> take 1.200.0 -> change to 1.200.1"

"Gitlab job run (2) -> take 1.200.1 -> change to 1.200.2"

"Gitlab job run (10) -> take 1.200.9 -> change to 1.201.0"

"Gitlab job run (xx) -> take 1.999.9 -> change to 2.000.0"
```

Command will run as a one liner in `gitlab ci`

Comment: "1.200.1 will increase to 1.200.2 ... 1.201.1, 1.202.2 ..."    from   1.201.1 => to 1.202.2 ??? Can you explain that ?

Comment: I meant - every run of script should take <value> ex. 1.200.1 and return 1.200.1 ++ ex. 1.200.2 ... after 9 script runs it should third part change to 0 and second do 201 -> 1.201.0

Comment: If it is `1.999.9` then should it become `2.000.0` ?

Comment: yes, I think we can delete delimeter, increase number and add delimeter

Comment: So `9.999.9` will become `10.000.0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat version.txt
1.2.3
$ awk -F. 'BEGIN{ OFS="." }{ $3++; if ($3>9){ $2++; $3=0 }; print $1,$2,$3 }' version.txt
1.2.4
```

Now I should explain this code, but it's to simple to explain.

EDIT:

- this looks for "config_version"
- this uses gawk
- this is a one-liner

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="." }/config_version/{match($0,/([0-9]+)+.([0-9]+)+.([0-9])+/,a); a[3]++; if(a[3]>9) { a[3]=0; a[2]++ }; if(a[2]>999){ a[2]=0; a[1]++ }; print "config_version = \"" a[1],a[2],a[3]"\""}!/config_version/'  version.txt > version.tmp; cp version.tmp version.txt
```

or (just for better readability)

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="." }
     /config_version/{match($0,/([0-9]+)+.([0-9]+)+.([0-9])+/,a);
       a[3]++; 
       if(a[3]>9) { a[3]=0; a[2]++ }; 
       if(a[2]>999){ a[2]=0; a[1]++ }; 
       print "config_version = \"" a[1],a[2],a[3]"\""}
     !/config_version/'  version.txt > version.tmp; cp version.tmp version.txt
```

- lines match `config_version` will be matched, and incremented
- lines match `config_version` will be copied without change
- output is send to `version.tmp`. If you use `version.txt` as output you will be left with a zero byte length file..

Comment: the problem is that from file I am taking config_version = "1.2.3" and as output I have 1.2.3 but I need to take that output and increase this number 123++ and all should be one liner

Comment: @anynewscom: With small changes with GNU awk: `awk -F '[."]' 'BEGIN{ OFS="." }/config_version/{ $4++; if ($4>9){ $3++; $4=0 }; $0=$1 "\"" $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 "\""}1' version.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus: Please test with `config_version = "1.999.9"` and `config_version = "9.999.9"`

Comment: @anubhava: I suspect this is a fundamental problem in Luuk's code.

Comment: I still need to use as input config_version = "x.x.x", in the file is more than one line with same pattern like config

Comment: I made an EDIT, because i did miss an important part of the question 

Comment: Thank you Luuk, is it possible to make awk output to sed input ? it will be easier than copying files

Comment: awk keeps file open until it finished. I am not sure how to do it with `sed`, and without copying....

Answer (score 3):

another `awk`
using @EdMorton's input file

```
$ awk 'function join(a,k,s,sep) {for(k in a) {s=s sep a[k]; sep="."}
                                 return s}
       BEGIN {FS=OFS="\""}
       /^config_version / {for(i=split($2,v,"."); i; i--)
                               {if(length(v[i]+1) > length(v[i]) && i>1) gsub(/./,0,v[i]); 
                                else {v[i]++; break}}
                           $2=join(v)}1' file


config_version = "1.9.9"
config_version = "1.9.90"
config_version = "2.0.0"
config_version = "1.9.99"
config_version = "1.99.0"
config_version = "2.00.0"
config_version = "1.999.0"
config_version = "10.000.0"
config_version = "9.99.99.000.0"
config_version = "10.00.00.000.0"
```

split the number into components and implement a full adder, finally join the number back and print.

Comment: Nice approach but `for (k in a)` will visit the elements in `a[]` in an unpredictable (usually hash) order, it needs to be `for (k=1; k in a; k++)` to guarantee to retain the original order. Another minor item is that `k`, `s`, and `sep` should be function-local variables and so your function declaration should be `join(a,    k,s,sep)` which has the side-effect that you can then remove the line `s=sep=""`.

Comment: Thx. I changed the `s, sep` to function-local.  For arrays though at least for small integers the hash order is the same as the numerical order, so should work fine here.

Comment: Though usually the case you can't rely on any given awk accessing array indices with `in` using hash order as the order is undefined per POSIX - [for (variable in array) which shall iterate, assigning each index of array to variable in an unspecified order.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). Even an awk that uses hash order today could do something else in future causing scripts that rely on that to break.

Comment: The convention for function local variables is to put a lof of white space between the real function args and those variables so it's obvious why they are in the arg list so you should use spaces or tabs to make it look like `join(a,     k,s,sep)` instead of `join(a,k,s,sep)`.

Comment: Coming back to the `in` operator for a second - even in gawk which I think probably uses hash order (though the gawk documentation just says `the order in which a ‘for (indx in array)’ loop scans an array is not defined`), you could tweak the script in future to set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"` or something elsewhere in the script for some other purpose and by doing so inadvertently break the `join()` function. It's just not worth relying on `for (k in a)` using a specific order, especially in cases like this where it's trivial to specify the order `for (k=1;k in a;k++)`.

Comment: I still need to use as input config_version = "x.x.x", in the file is more than one line with same pattern like config

Answer (score 2):

Considering this input file:

```sh
cat file

config_version = "1.999.9"
config_version = "1.200.9"
config_version = "1.000.0"
config_version = "9.999.9"
```

You may try this `awk` to increment version number:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/"/, "", $NF); split($NF, a, "."); $NF=""; n = a[1] a[2] "." a[3]; s = sprintf("%.1f", n + .1); p = length(s)-5; print $0 "\"" substr(s, 1, p) "." substr(s, p+1) "\""}' file

config_version = "2.000.0"
config_version = "1.201.0"
config_version = "1.000.1"
config_version = "10.000.0"
```

Expanded form of `awk`:

```sh
awk '{
   gsub(/"/, "", $NF)
   split($NF, a, ".")
   $NF = ""
   n = a[1] a[2] "." a[3]
   s = sprintf("%.1f", n + .1)
   p = length(s) - 5
   print $0 "\"" substr(s, 1, p) "." substr(s, p+1) "\""
}' file
```

Comment: I still need to use as input config_version = "x.x.x", in the file is more than one line with same pattern like config

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
config_version = "1.9.8"
config_version = "1.9.89"
config_version = "1.9.9"
config_version = "1.9.98"
config_version = "1.98.9"
config_version = "1.99.9"
config_version = "1.998.9"
config_version = "9.999.9"
config_version = "9.99.98.999.9"
config_version = "9.99.99.999.9"
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
{
    orig = $0
    newNum = oldStr = $2
    gsub(/\./,"",newNum)
    newNum++
    newStr = ""
    while ( match(oldStr,/[^.]+$/) ) {
        digsBeg = length(newNum) - RLENGTH + 1
        newStr  = substr(newNum,digsBeg) (newStr == "" ? "" : "." newStr)
        oldStr  = substr(oldStr,1,RSTART-2)
        newNum  = substr(newNum,1,digsBeg - 1)
    }
    $2 = newNum newStr
    print orig "\t->\t" $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
config_version = "1.9.8"        ->      config_version = "1.9.9"
config_version = "1.9.89"       ->      config_version = "1.9.90"
config_version = "1.9.9"        ->      config_version = "2.0.0"
config_version = "1.9.98"       ->      config_version = "1.9.99"
config_version = "1.98.9"       ->      config_version = "1.99.0"
config_version = "1.99.9"       ->      config_version = "2.00.0"
config_version = "1.998.9"      ->      config_version = "1.999.0"
config_version = "9.999.9"      ->      config_version = "10.000.0"
config_version = "9.9.98.999.9" ->      config_version = "9.9.99.000.0"
config_version = "9.9.99.999.9" ->      config_version = "10.0.00.000.0"
```

Comment: I still need to use as input config_version = "x.x.x", in the file is more than one line with same pattern like config

Comment: as well one liner is very important in that because I cant use script files and other methods. my file includes test_version = "x.x.x" config_number = "x.x.x" anc config_version = "x.x.x" as origin, so taking config_version, increment and save to origin file is the solution I need, I hope its just something small to add and as one liner it will be best working solution

Comment: Fix your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can use to fully test a potential solution.

Comment: Hope its now more easier explained

Comment: See the sample input I created for a useful set to test a potential solution against and add other lines you would not want modified to that. Then see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format sample input and expected output correctly and do THAT in your question.

Comment: I repaired my input and output, so what is important is to have awk that take the value, transforming it and then do output to sed to the file

Comment: The input in your question isn't adequate to test a potential solution against which is why we've all had to make up our own input to test with BUT we guessed wrong at what the input should be which is why you're asking for updates now. To avoid that happening again take the input from my answer, any other input you consider missing from my answer and use THAT as the sample input for your question and add the expected output for that input.

Comment: Why are you still posting comments about this though - you already accepted an answer so I assume that does what you want otherwise why accept it? Also, what makes you think you have to use sed for something, you never need sed when you're using awk?

Comment: During my tests I changed requirements. I am not using awk/sed daily, its the thing I am only doing as support to someone

Comment: If you'd like further help ask a new question that includes a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask] if that's not clear,